# Equivalent to PerformClick() for a toggle button in C#?

Tags: c#, click, togglebutton

I'm using a toggle button which calls a function when Cliked and I'd like to call the Click event just as PerformClick would do for a simple button from C# code.

How can I do that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle button"? Do you mean Checkbox with a button appearance? Then you can simply use the CheckedChanged-Event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper methods are easy and effective for this, example follows:

```
// Assume this is your actual event handler
private void anyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    performSomeCode();
}

private void performSomeCode()
{
    //here goes your code
}
```

Decoupling UI from logic in this fashion, if/when you need to pretend the event was fired you simply have to invoke `performSomeCode()`, making the real UI irrelevant.